# Library to check connection speed

Tags: java, networking, performance, monitoring

I have two servers with Apache Tomcat that once in a while, connect to share data. One of them is mobile, so the Internet connectivity changes. From this second, I need to store data about how the connection is (ping, speed) to the other server at different times of the day (so I can check when is a good moment for the transfer).

Does any one know about some Java library that can help on that?

I've seen some questions about this in the site, but no one talks about any library, only direct programming

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) from Apache.

Comment: +1 : JMeter can let you create scenario tests and store the data.

Comment: Tests? I need to check connection speed.

Comment: @Mateu: I'm not saying its easy to use the library but their library can do load testing, have a look here: http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/17950/0/page/3

Comment: Ok, that's true. However I hope that there is a simpler way

Comment: You can always download and upload a rather big file but then you have to do it yourself and that's also not a "real world measurement"...